# looping through a pandas dataframe and applying an if esle function

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance

I am trying to build a simple backtester using python, the backtester works by comparing 2 values in a certain time, as (at time x check if indicator_value > ohlc_value: order_type = 1; else order type will be = 0)

```
data = {'time':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'ohlc':[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5,1.66], 'indicator':[1.05, 1.22, 1.4, 1.55, 1.6,1.77]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

how can i set those values?

```
if data['ohlc'] > data['indicator']:
      data['order_type'] = 1
else:
      data['order_type'] = 0
```

I know I cant loop dataframes like that.

Comment: data['order_type'] = data['ohlc'] > data['indicator']

Comment: Didn't notice @Balaji's answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
df['order_type'] = (df['ohlc'] > df['indicator']).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   time  ohlc  indicator  order_type
0     0  1.10       1.05           1
1     1  1.20       1.22           0
2     2  1.30       1.40           0
3     3  1.40       1.55           0
4     4  1.50       1.60           0
5     5  1.66       1.77           0
```

If you have custom values to assign based on different conditions, here' one way to go (the default is `0`):

```py
import numpy as np
conditions = [df['ohlc'] > df['indicator']]
choices = [-1]
df['order_type'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   time  ohlc  indicator  order_type
0     0  1.10       1.05          -1
1     1  1.20       1.22           0
2     2  1.30       1.40           0
3     3  1.40       1.55           0
4     4  1.50       1.60           0
5     5  1.66       1.77           0
```

Comment: thank you, but in case i need to set the order_type to -1, can this be done the same way?

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this

```
def fun(row):
    return 1 if row['ohlc']>row['indicator'] else 0 

df['order_type']=df.apply(fun,axis=1)
df
```